# Has any one created add on tile for Undermountain Games' DTiles: Dungeons?

Tags: dungeon, tiles

I have been using **[Undermountain Games' DTiles: Dungeons!](http://www.undermountaingames.com/)** for a while now and it is a great product, but ...

there are limited floor types. It would be nice to have water and magma etc. I tried to create a jpg to do water and it did not work. Has any one else?

I also have wondered if you could create different wall edge types, ie a more cave like one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is:

### Floor Tiles

1. Create four jpeg images at 400 by 400 pixels (say water1.jpg to water4.jpg)
2. Copy them into the DTiles directory
3. Edit the library.ini file and add in a line like below after the [Floors] tag:

   water1.jpg|0|X:\DTiles\water1.jpg|X:\DTiles\water2.jpg|X:\DTiles\water3.jpg|X:\DTiles\water4.jpg
4. here is an [example](http://www.ironfort.net/files/example.zip) unpack in your DTiles directory.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the stuff available for other mapping programs.  DTiles looks like it will work with most of them.

- [RPTools](http://forums.rptools.net/viewforum.php?f=8) has a fair number of free images available.
- [Campaign Cartographers guild](http://www.cartographersguild.com/) has a large number of user provided images

Answer (score 2):

I haven't but I would recommend you try [The Cartographers Guild](http://www.cartographersguild.com/forum.php) as they are experts on this particular subject :)